# ODE $Aw'' + iBw' + cw=0$ with complex coefficients, how to solve?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the ODE for $w:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ :
$$Aw'' + iBw' + cw=0$$
where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is a complex number. There is a boundary condition involving $w_y$. Also $w$ should vanish at infinity.

Can someone tell me how to find the solution this type of complex equation?

Comment: Formally, this is the same as solving second-order, linear, homogeneous o.d.e.s with a real coefficients.

Comment: @Travis do you mean because, assume $w$ is real-valued, then since teh ODE equals zero the real part and imaginary part of the LHS of the ODE must both be zero. Right??? But this gives me a second order ODE and a first order ODE that w should simultaneously solve. Isn't that a problem??